# Альтернатива функции date_diff()

Tags: дата, php

Привет всем! В PHP 5.3 вышла некая функция `date_diff()`. А на хостинге 5.2 есть ли альтернатива функции `date_diff()`?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос рассматривался на stackoverflow: [Undefined date_diff()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475646/undefined-date-diff).

---

[пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3475659/4827341):

```
<?php 
function date_diff($date1, $date2) { 
    $current = $date1; 
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2); 
    $count = 0; 
    while(date_create($current) < $datetime2){ 
        $current = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current))); 
        $count++; 
    } 
    return $count; 
} 

echo (date_diff('2010-3-9', '2011-4-10')." days <br \>"); 
?>
```